# What if Someone Washes Out as a Jedi or Jedi Padawan?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

After reading [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9066/1693) to an earlier question of mine, and seeing the reference to someone working as an archivist for the Jedi, that raises another question for me.

What do the Jedi do when someone washes out as a Padawan, or becomes a Jedi and eventually realizes they no longer believe in the Jedi way or another reason develops that they must leave the order?

Since they start training Jedi at such a young age (judging from the younglings Yoda was working with in *Attack of the Clones*), I would think that along the way a number of those in training find they don't want to be Jedi, or that the Jedi instructors find they won't fit in with the Jedi way.

I would think they'd handle it differently, depending on how advanced someone was when issues came up.  I did find [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5623/how-do-jedi-leave-the-jedi-order) that is related to this, but is about how they leave and there's no much information on that.  (I know it's a life long path, but there are always exceptions to everything, especially with sentient beings who can grow and change.)

What do Jedi do when someone in training or an actual Jedi reach a point where they no longer fit in with the Jedi order?

Comment: They get killed. Or, [WORSE](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0241527/quotes?qt=qt0368097) - **expelled**

Comment: @DVK: No, ex-spelled is what happens when you wash out at Hogwarts.

Comment: They go on to be involved in [every major event](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tag_and_Bink) in the Star Wars universe.

Comment: I don't remember which book it was, but it's stated that Obi-wan, as a Youngling, wasn't selected as a Padewan, and was sent away. Only through a twist of fate did he meet Qui-gon Jinn who eventually accepted him as his Padewan, turning back on his vow to never do so again (as his first apprentice turned to the dark side, I believe).

Comment: @Jersey - that's mostly detailed in the Jedi Apprentice series (YA)

Comment: They go on to become the janitor or the grounds keeper... :D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A special case is those who wash out as a result of not passing their [Initiate tests](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Initiate_Trials), required to progress from Youngling/Initiate to Padawan. For those who still wish to use their Force abilities to the betterment of people, there are Jedi-run [Service Corps](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Service_Corps) (the Agricultural Corps, the Medical Corps, the Educational Corps, and the Exploration Corps). Some Jedi served in those as well, but they were the main/default career path for those who didn't make it as Padawans.

Members of service corps were still considered "Jedi", but of course not "Jedi Knights".

They made their first appearance in "*Jedi Apprentice*" book series.

---

Aside from that, there were a number of people who left the Jedi Order after becoming Padawans, either voluntarily or not.

Twenty of them were Jedi Masters when the left (The [Lost Twenty](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Twenty))

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Former_Jedi has a list.

For the former, there's no special procedure, though one could formally declare the resignation (e.g. [Serifa Altunen](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Serifa_Altunen) resigning formally once Anakin and Obi-Wan tried to convince her to come re-join the Jedi after she became disenchanted with Jedi participation in Clone Wars). This seems to have frequently involved turning in one's lightsaber and robes, but I was never able to find a source stating it to be a rule.

Some leave and become regular people (though frequently becoming leaders).

Some leave to pursue their specific path ([Danni Quee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Danni_Quee) going to live on Zonama Sekot).

Some leave and become Sith apprentices and lead Separatist rebellions :)

Comment: Do you have any idea what percentage of Jedi who leave take that last path you mentioned (leading rebellions)?

Comment: What's amazing about the Wookiepedia (or Wikipedia) is that there are all these topics, like "Former Jedi," that you'd never think to look up as an actual topic.

Comment: @TangoOversway - not sure about the percentage, but you do have Dooku (intentionally) and then Anakin (tricked)

Comment: @TangoOversway - I'm only aware of Dooku. Anakin didn't lead anything, he just did what Vader told him to.

Comment: @DVK: I'm confused by your last statement. Anakin *is* Vader; and became a powerful general in his own right following his turning.

Comment: @WillihamTotland - Vader didn't LEAD anything. He was Palpatine's servant. Oh. I see. Just noticed the typo. Meant to say "Anakin didn't lead anything, he just did what **Emperor** told him to"

Comment: @DVK: Any officer in an army leads; generals most of all. The very notion that Palpatine provided Darth Vader with every tactical decision over the course of some 30 years is preposterous.

Comment: @WillihamTotland - OK, bad wording on my part. Vader didn't lead rebellions (or any large movements).

Answer (score 8):

Yes and no. Ejected Jedi and Padawans who fail the trials are given over to the care of the Reassignment Council, a body tasked with finding suitable employment outside the Jedi Path.

This [council](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Council_of_Reassignment) appears in a considerable number of Jedi books and EU media. Failed Jedi are generally reassigned to one of four **"[service corps](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Service_Corps)**" comprising;

- The Agricultural Corps
- The Medical Corps
- The Educational Corps
- The Exploration Corps

[image: Jedi Path]

To offer some examples, [Lorian Nod](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lorian_Nod) (who appears in the book "[Legacy of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Jedi)") is expelled from the Jedi Order. He is then reassigned to an agricultural research station.

The [Jedi Path handbook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_%28real-life_book%29) also mentions another past failure (Half-Moonsing) who now serves in the Jedi Temple and has responsibility for vehicle maintenance.

[image: Jedi Path]