# Was Anakin Skywalker ever disciplined by the Jedi Order for his many acts of disobedience?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker

Anakin Skywalker as a Jedi apprentice and knight was reckless, arrogant, and often directly disobedient. Many of his actions violated long-standing Jedi policies. (e.g. - don't kill except in self-defense, don't torture, don't start romantic relationships with anyone, etc...)

This video shows he violates Jedi rules several times in front of other Jedi, (e.g. - Yoda, Kenobi, and Ahsoka), so the Jedi knew. Did the Jedi Council do nothing?

An [answer to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126142/what-punishment-would-anakin-have-faced-if-the-jedi-council-had-found-out-he-sla) says the only punishment for breaking certain rules is expulsion from the Jedi Order. He committed several violations with full knowledge of what he was doing and in front of other Jedi, yet he was never expelled.

Was he ever disciplined or punished by the Jedi Council for his many acts of disobedience?

Comment: Well he never makes it to Jedi Master rank (despite being much more powerful than a lot of Masters)

Comment: I'm not a big enough fan to properly answer this one, but my impression was always that one of Obi-Wan's biggest failures as a teacher to Anakin was failing to properly discipline him when he broke the rules.  Apparently the rest of the council left it up to Obi-Wan to keep his student in line.

Comment: The Jedi thought Anakin was the Chosen One, they probably didn't want to risk expelling him and have him go rogue or Dark (even though he did anyway). People of privilege tend to get away with a lot of things that others wouldn't.

Comment: Remy makes a good point.  Think of all the nonsense Harry Potter got away with for being "The Chosen One"

Comment: @RichS Admittedly Anakin often got verbally disciplined from Obi wan for his recklessness - see episodes six and seven of the first series of the clone wars in which Kenobi gives Anakin verbal stick for loosing R2-D2